# Create a Console Application in Java using netbeans?

Tags: java, c#, netbeans, console-application

I am .net and java developer but I don't know/remember how to open the windows console in java. What I want is quite simple. 
Here is the csharp

```
 System.Console.WriteLine("Hello C# 6: how is Roselyn?");
```

and the java

```
 System.out.prinln("Hello Java 8: How do you treat lambda expressions?.");
```

I dont want the java program to show this message within netbean console but I want it to prompt me the windows console as c# do.

Comment: Run the program outside of netbeans then. Also, it's System.out.println(), not System.out.Prinln().

Comment: FYKI,C# is totally Microsoft related language,so they have provided the facility of opening the windows console in Java.Can you implement it on Linux/Unix machines???`No,youcan't!` 
So,a direct response to your answer is no,you have to use Netbeans window,else try in C# only,or use console running of Java application!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just Netbeans redirecting the standard output to its console. You can set this up in Visual Studio, too, but it's not by default.